# How can I edit colors and set limits for a ggplot contour map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour

I use ggplot's `geom_contour_filled` to plot this map. I want to change the legend ranges from -2 to 11, like I wrote in the argument `breaks = c(-Inf,-2., -1.5, -1., -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11,Inf)`, but the plot only shows the color that appears in the graph. Also, ggplot automatically set the colors for the variables, but is it possible to edit the color of the contour?

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(map, aes(y=Latitude, x=Longitude, z=variable)) +
  ggtitle(title)+
  geom_contour_filled(breaks = c(-Inf,-2., -1.5, -1., -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11,Inf))+
  geom_map(data=world, map=world,
           aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
           size=0.1, fill=NA, color = "grey") + #America and Greenland
  geom_map(data=canada, map=canada,
           aes(long, lat, map_id=id),
           size=0.2, fill=NA, color = "black")+ #Canada
  xlim(-146,-44)+
  ylim(35,90)+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

My current map:
[image: My current map]

My desired map:
[image: My goal map looks like]

Comment: Have you tried something like `scale_fill_brewer`? https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_brewer.html

Comment: Thank you so much! I found it useful, but how can I make a custom palette?

Comment: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_manual.html